# Can you make comments as the User using facebook sdk?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

This might already be asked but I just searched through for hours. I am trying to comment on a post that I made with my web app while signed in on facebook. I do not want to post a comment as the Web app page admin. Id like to post the comment as a user signed into facebook on my site while the post id is remembered. when I try to post a comment I get this

```
 Publishing comments through the API is only available for page access tokens
```

I'm using this piece of code

```
FB.api(response.data[0].id+'/comments', 'post',{message: "good work"},function(response){
                            console.log(response);
                          });
```

I'm starting to think that it is not possible anymore. I just would like someone to give me a concrete answer about it thank you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, as long as their logged in, they can do the same thing they would normally able to do, using the JavaScript SDK.

Comment: I dont know how to obtain and use the page access token or even if it is the right way because its mentioning page admin.

Comment: What is `response.data[0]`?

Comment: Its the id of a comment. I tried it with the id of the post itself too and got the same result

Comment: Did you test to see if the Client is logged in? If not, they can't comment. In other words, you cannot comment for someone else.

Comment: I am logged in as myself

Comment: I posted on my own timeline with the web app im making then getting the id returned after posting and trying to put a comment on it.

Comment: You used [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/), Asynchronously?

Comment: Yes. I saved the access token it gave me but im not sure where its used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message tells you that it is not possible to comment "as User" anymore. You can only comment with a Page Token, which means that you can only comment "as Page".

Changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version2.10#gapi-90-comments

> POST and DELETE /{object-id}/comments — This node now requires a valid
>   page access token.

Answer (score -1):

Basic Full Page Login Example:

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* external.js */
var doc, bod, I, fI, old = onload; // for use on other loads
onload = function(){
if(old)old(); // change old var name if using technique on other pages

doc = document; bod = doc.body;
I = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
fI = function(client_id, redirect_uri, onLogin, onLoginContext){
  var c = onLoginContext || this;
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(r){
    if(r.status === 'connected'){
      onLogin.call(c);
    }               
    else{
      location = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id='+client_id+'&redirect_uri='+redirect_uri;
    }
  });
}
var out = I('out');
fI('571652776188445', 'https://phpglue.com/fakebook', function(){
  FB.api('708713672667337', 'post', {message:'Testing Facebook JavaScript SDK'}, function(r){
    out.innerHTML = r.message;
  });
}); // app I will never fully develop

}
//]]>
```

```css
/* external.css */
html,body{
  padding:0; margin:0;
}
body{
  background:#000; overflow-y:scroll;
}
.main{
  width:936px; background:#fff; padding:20px; margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width' />
    <title>Facebook Basic Full Page Login</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <div id='out'>You have to test this from Your Facebook App</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```